# Pattern matching a list of list

Tags: coq

I have a `list list nat` I want to write a function to parse into this list, for example:

```
Definition my_function (l : list list nat) :=
 let fix aux acc l :=
    match l with
    | nil => acc
    | c :: l' => match c with
                 | nil => acc
                 | d :: l'' => aux d l'
                end
     end in aux 0 l.
```

Here I don't know how can I use the `l''`. Is there a better way to write this function? Thank you very much.

EDIT: I want to know about the algorithm that I can check the whole list `l`.

Comment: Can you try to explain better what you want to do with this function? Right now it is returning the first element of the list right before the first empty list, and I don't know why you'd need `l''` there.

Comment: Could you also write syntactically correct Coq please ? I don't know if you ask about the syntax or about some unexplain algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what your function is supposed to accomplish, but it should
  have this shape:

```
Axioms (s1 s2 s3 : Set) (f3 : s3) (f4 : s1 -> s3 -> s3) (f1 : s2)
  (f2 : s3 -> s2 -> s2).

Fixpoint my_funct_aux (l1 : list s1) : s3 :=
  match l1 with
  | nil        => f3
  | cons e1 l2 => f4 e1 (my_funct_aux l2)
  end.

Fixpoint my_funct (l1 : list (list s1)) : s2 :=
  match l1 with
  | nil        => f1
  | cons l2 l3 => f2 (my_funct_aux l2) (my_funct l3)
  end.
```

Or, if you don't mind the [terseness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29):

```
Axioms (s1 s2 s3 : Set) (f3 : s3) (f4 : s1 -> s3 -> s3) (f1 : s2)
  (f2 : s3 -> s2 -> s2).

Fixpoint fold {s1 s2 : Set}
  (f1 : s2) (f2 : s1 -> s2 -> s2) (l1 : list s1) : s2 :=
  match l1 with
  | nil        => f1
  | cons e1 l2 => f2 e1 (fold f1 f2 l2)
  end.

Definition my_funct : list (list s1) -> s2 :=
  fold f1 (fun l1 l2 => f2 (fold f3 f4 l1) l2).
```